# RaiseError did not raise the error enough?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, t-sql, ado.net

Why the error does not appear at the UI layer?  I am using ExecuteScaler

```
BEGIN CATCH

  PRINT N'The transaction is in an uncommittable state. Rolling back transaction.'
  ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;

  DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000);
  DECLARE @ErrorSeverity INT;
  DECLARE @ErrorState INT;

  SELECT @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE(),
         @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(),
         @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE();

  RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage, 
             @ErrorSeverity,
             @ErrorState);

END CATCH
```

Thanks

Comment: @ONG Ponies: looks identical on this page that the link you posted links to: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx (apart from the rollback)

Comment: Is the rollback transaction reseting the error?

Comment: I don't get it what about  RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage, 
             @ErrorSeverity,
             @ErrorState); it suppose to raise the error if the level is 16 regrdless of anything

Comment: How are you catching it?

Comment: I am not catching it I want it to fire at .Net level.

Comment: @Costa, `RAISERROR(@ErrorMessage,@ErrorSeverity,@ErrorState)` does **not** raise the error level to 16 regardless of anything, it raises it to `@ErrorSeverity`.

Comment: In management studio the error severity is 16, but nothing populate to UI, sorry I was not clear!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only raise user messages, system messages can only be raised by the engine:

> Error numbers for user-defined error
>   messages should be greater than 50000.
>   When msg_id is not specified,
>   RAISERROR raises an error message with
>   an error number of 50000.

Therefore you cannot raise the original `@ErrorMessage`, you have to raise a *new* error code.

Also, your catch block is incorrect in as it *assumes* an uncommittable transaction. This is not always the case, you **must** check the result of [`XACT_STATE()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189797.aspx) before deciding if the transaction is doomed. There are many cases on which the error handling can *continue* the transaction. See [Exception handling and nested transactions](http://rusanu.com/2009/06/11/exception-handling-and-nested-transactions/).

Comment: Is there a problem in rolling back a commitable transaction?

Comment: @Costa: Commit or rollback committable transactions depends entirely on business logic. But in any case, at least don't print `the transaction is in uncommittable state` if it is not so.

Answer (score 0):

First, review Remus's article on error handling in nested transactions, so you understand the full scope of things.

Then, try forcing the error level to 16. Also, embed the original error information in the error message when you rethrow the error, so you don't lose that information:

```
BEGIN TRY
  SELECT 1/0
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH

  DECLARE 
    @ErrorMessage  NVARCHAR(4000)
  , @ErrorNumber   INT
  , @ErrorSeverity INT
  , @ErrorState    INT
  , @ErrorLine     INT

  SELECT 
    @ErrorNumber   = ERROR_NUMBER()
  , @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY()
  , @ErrorState    = ERROR_STATE()
  , @ErrorLine     = ERROR_LINE();

  SET @ErrorMessage 
    = '>> Msg %i, Level %i, State %i, Line %i'
    + CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+ERROR_MESSAGE()

  RAISERROR (
    @ErrorMessage,16,1
  , @ErrorNumber
  , @ErrorSeverity
  , @ErrorState
  , @ErrorLine
  )

END CATCH
```